# Confusion with $\int_{C}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I must solve $\int_{C}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 -1}dz$ where $c:= \{ z \; : \; |z-a|=a\}$ and $a > 1$.

I wish to apply the Cauchy Integral Formula (or generalized).

The only singularities inside the region covered by the contour is $z_0 = 1, z_1 = \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \;z_2 = \frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

By taking small circles $C_0,C_1,C_2$ around $z_0,z_1,z_2$ respectively, we have
$$\int_{C}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 -1}dz = \int_{C_0}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 -1}dz + \int_{C_1}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 -1}dz + \int_{C_2}\frac{ze^z}{z^6 -1}dz$$

My troubling is transforming the function into something usable for Generalized Cauchy Integral Formula.

Answer (score 0):

I will be following your notation. If $z_3=-1/2(1-i\sqrt{3})$, $z_4=-1/2(1+i\sqrt{3})$ and $z_5=-1$, then of course 
$$
z^6-1=(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)(z-z_5)
$$
As you noted, $z_3,z_4$ and $z_5$ are not in the region bounded by $C$, then by taking $C_j$ small circles around $z_j$, $j=0,1,2$, by the Cauchy Integral Formula
$$
\int_{C_j} \frac{ze^z}{z^6-1}dz = \int_{C_j} \frac{ze^z}{(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)(z-z_5)}dz = 2\pi i \cdot f_j(z_j)
$$ 
where, for $j=0,1,2$ 
$$
f_j(z)= \frac{ze^z}{\displaystyle \prod_{k\in \{ 0, \cdots, 5\}\backslash\{ j\}} (z-z_k)}
$$
*Can you take it now from here?*

PD: Since $j=0,1,2$, perhaps for the calculations it will be useful to use that
$$
(z-z_3)(z-z_4)(z-z_5)=(z^2+z+1)(z+1)=z^3+2z^2+2z+1
$$